# QDA number of parameters

Tags: classification

If we include to Linear Discriminant Analysis quadratic parameters we get Quadratic Discriminant Analysis classifier. Number of parameters is $(K-1)\times[(p\times(p+3)/2) + 1]$ where K is number of classes and p is number of features.

Why $K-1$? In the book it is said that we only need to compare $\delta_{k}(x) - \delta_{K}(x)$ of discriminant functions of some prespecified class K, but why do we do that and how it works?

$(p\times(p+3)/2) + 1$ is number of factors in multivariate quadratic function how is it calculated?

Answer (score 1):

First, for one klass $k$ we need to calculate the following parameters:

- 1 probability prior; $\hat \pi_k = N_k/N$,
- $p$ class means; $\hat \mu_k = \sum_{g_1 = k} x_i/N_k$ and
- $p(p+1)/2$ parameters for the covariance matrix.

Where $N_k$ is the number of class-$k$ observations and $N$ the total number of observations.

Putting this together gives us $1 + p + p(p+1)/2 = p(p+3)/2 + 1$ total parameters to estimate for each class.

Note that in QDA (unlike LDA) we do not assume that the covariance matrices are the same between classes and thus need to estimate it for each class.

Now, this is the number of parameters for each class but we have $K$ classes. However, since every observation belongs to one class it is enough to estimate $K-1$ classes. Any observation that is not in any of these $K-1$ classes will be in the $K$:th class.

Thus, the total number of parameters in QDA is
$$ (K-1) \cdot \left( \frac{p(p+3)}{2} + 1 \right) $$